# Google Custom Search API HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Tags: python, google-api, http-status-code-403

I have a simple Python script which will download images for specific queries from Google Custom Search API.
Unfortunately, after two queries to the API, the script shows a 403 error.

Can someone help me solving this issue?

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from time import sleep
import os
import urllib.request

Read the data from the Excel file
data = pd.read_excel('swimages.xlsx')

Create directory to save images if it doesn't exist
if not os.path.exists('swieci-images'):
os.makedirs('swieci-images')

API parameters
cx = 'mykey'  # Replace with your Custom Search JSON API cx
api_key = 'mykey'  # Replace with your API Key

for index, row in data.iterrows():
query = row['query']
filename = row['filename']

Define the endpoint and parameters
url = f"https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q={query}&num=3&start=1&lr=lang_pl&safe=off&cx={cx}&searchType=image&key={api_key}"

Make the request
response = requests.get(url)

Log the response
print(f"Response for {query}: {response.json()}")

Check if the request was successful
if response.status_code == 200:
Parse the response JSON
results = response.json()

Iterate over the results and save the images
for i, item in enumerate(results.get('items', []), start=1):
Get the link to the image
link = item['link']

Download and save the image
urllib.request.urlretrieve(link, f'swieci-images/{filename}-{i}.png')

Sleep for 2 seconds to avoid rate limits
sleep(60)
```

Error which I am getting:

```
/usr/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py in http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
    641 class HTTPDefaultErrorHandler(BaseHandler):
    642     def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
--> 643         raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    644 
    645 class HTTPRedirectHandler(BaseHandler):

HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

I have tried to change API token and using other one.
I have tried to put limit (10s wait time per request).
I have tried to execute script via Google Colab and my local env
I have tried to debug code with ChatGPT
Nothing helped me solving this issue

Comment: Did you replace the value of `api_key ` as you should have ?

Comment: Yes of course :) I deleted them for privacy concerns.